# what orderings are guaranteed by the ARM weak memory model

Tags: arm, multicore, memory-model

I understand the basic differences b/w a weak and strong memory model. 
But there is no exact definition of weak and it depends on the architecture (here ARM).

I have gone through the documentation on ARM infocenter but still not clear on a lot of things.
Can somebody please list out -

**what memory access orderings are guaranteed by ARM.**

And hence **what orderings must an assembly programmer explicitly enforce in code**, when coding for a multi-core ARM system.


*Bonus points for anyone who can explain the differences b/w ARM and PPC(Power PC) memory models.*

Answer (score 2):

Check out the [Cortex-A Series Programmer's Guide](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.den0013b/index.html), it has a chapter on memory ordering. For example:

> Three memory types are defined in the ARM Architecture. All regions of
>   memory are configured as one of these three types.
>
> - Strongly-ordered
> - Device
> - Normal.
>
> In addition, for normal and device memory, it is possible to specify
>   whether the memory is shareable (accessed by other agents) or not. For
>   normal memory, inner and outer cacheable properties can be specified.